# useSelector is not able to export from 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I have an error that says `Can't import 'UseSelector' from react-redux`. What I'm making is a small project called **Getting started** I'm using firebase and react to do this, here is the code file where the error came

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {createFirestoreInstance, reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase, reactReduxFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase';



`
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {attachAuthIsReady:true, firebase:'firebaseReducer'})    )
);


const rrfProps = {
    firebase,
    config: fbConfig,
    dispatch: store.dispatch,
    createFirestoreInstance,
    userProfile: 'users', // where profiles are stored in database
    presence: 'presence', // where list of online users is stored in database
    sessions: 'sessions'
}




function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
    const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
    if (!isLoaded(auth)) return <div>Loading Screen...</div>;
        return children
}

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
 
    
    
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
            <AuthIsLoaded>
                <App />
                </AuthIsLoaded>
            </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root'));
    serviceWorker.unregister();
    
    
})
```

I have tried restarting npm start, installing react-redux again then restarting npm start, running npm install and closing Vscode then reopening it. That what I tried I'm very confused about why it didn't work but please help me fix this, thank you :D.

Comment: What version of react-redux do you have installed? How did you update react-redux? Did you actually install the new version or just specify it in package.json?

Comment: You should install the package `npm install` too

Comment: @DrewReese im using version 6.14.6 of react-redux, how I install is running a command in the terminal npm install react-redux

Comment: @DennisVash I tried it right now but it didn't work :(

Comment: What version is in the package.json file? What version is in the package-lock.json file? Need to verify you really installed the latest version.

Comment: @DrewReese at package.json is 5.1.2 version and at package-lock.json is 5.1.2. guess I wasn't specific, sorry. but know what do I do?

Comment: Easy is to update the specified version in the package.json to the version you want and rerun `npm i`, or first uninstall the react-redux (to remove it from package.json), then install latest.

Comment: @DrewReese i will try that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[React Redux hooks were first added in v7.1.0](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#hooks) so you can't import `useSelector` hook if you are using React Redux v6.14.6 as you said.

It seems like you are working on a tutorial-like project, so I suppose you don't have any constraint about package versions and you can update it without significant problems.
Be aware that [React Redux 7.1 requires React 16.8.3 or later](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#installation), so check also React version in your `package.json` file.

Run:

```
npm uninstall react react-redux
npm i react react-redux
```

Then check in your `package.json` if `dependencies` entry contains `"react-redux": "^7.2.1"` and  `"react": "^16.13.1"`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to update your redux and react-redux version.
also, keep in mind you can not use "useSelector" hook out of the functional or arrow component and it must be a child of  from redux.